# IIS 8 hosts friendly url not working

Tags: iis-8

I am hosting an application on the local IIS-8 on Windows 8.1 pro 64-bit. I want to access this application with hostname like www.testing.com or testing.com inspite of IP 127.0.0.1 or localhost. I have changed the configuration in the hosts file.

Here is my configuration;

I have added following entries for the host at the last ;

```
127.0.0.1    testing.com
127.0.0.1    www.testing.com
```

Site view in connection pane looks like ;
**-Sites**
    -Default Web site
    -WebApp

Bindings are as below ;
Type:http
IP Address : All unassigned
host name  : testing.com

My problem is that the hosts file is being ignored and whenever I enter the address testing.com it redirects me to internet site testing.com and not locally hosted website.

Please let me know what extra settings or improvements are required for this.

Thanks in advance,
Anil

Comment: Are you sure you changed the hosts file? Try a `ping  testing.com`, does it use 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes I am sure, the location of file is c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc.

Comment: ping testing.com returns 208.48.81.134, and hosts entry is being ignored

Comment: So this has nothing to do with IIS, but the fact that your hosts files does not work. Weird.

Comment: Do you know the reason why it is being ignored ?

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot

Comment: Or how should I make it work.

Comment: Thanks Peter, your send link helped me, I read it thoroughly and found that Windows 8.1 was using hosts.ics , I modified it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this was not a problem with IIS but with the hosts file not working as expected.

To troubleshoot hosts file issues, use this [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot.)

In Anil's case the problem was the following file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.ics
```

If that file exists, the content of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` is ignored.

You can either review why hosts.ics is there and remove it, or add your custom entries to it.